# @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) not working

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, mongo-jackson-mapper

While serialization of the class DataType the dbOptions is been ignored but dataType is being printed with its value.

Note I need to ignore the these property only during serialization and not deserialization.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "dataType")
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DefaultType.class, name = "Default"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = NumberRangeType.class, name = "NumberRange"),

})
public abstract class DataType {

@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
protected String dataType;

@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
protected String dbOptions;

public String getDataType() {
    return dataType;
}

public void setDataType(String dataType) {
    this.dataType = dataType;
}

public String getDbOptions() {
    return dbOptions;
}

public void setDbOptions(String dbOptions) {
    this.dbOptions = dbOptions;
}


abstract
public void compute() throws ParseException;

}
```

Sample output is :

```
"options":{"dataType":"NumberRange","id":"1","min":0,"max":30}
```

Don't want dataType to get printed in the output

Answer (score 10):

It seems this unexpected behaviour is a bug (see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/935). So you have to work around the issue. One of the solutions is explained here http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/21/jackson-using-jsonignore-and-jsonproperty-annotations-to-exclude-a-property-only-from-json-deserialization/.

The following is an example from the latter link adapted to mimic the intended behaviour of the @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) annotation.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class User implements Serializable {

  @JsonIgnore
  private String password;

  @JsonIgnore
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```